# Устранение ошибок c log

Tags: php, логирование

Помогите определить ошибку в логах, сделав снимок капли (использую digital ocean) переместил работающий проект на новый сервер. (снимок капли делает полную копию всех настроек панели управления сервером и самого проекта).

Сменил домен айпи, но в логах веб сервера появляются три ошибки:

```
[Fri Sep 27 18:53:15.310579 2019] [:error] [pid 913] [client 157.245.138.57:46766] PHP Warning:  require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/admin/web/mysite.com/core/engine.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/mysite.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp) in /home/admin/web/mysite.com/public_html/index.php on line 5

[Fri Sep 27 19:01:30.182865 2019] [:error] [pid 914] [client 157.245.138.57:46826] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/admin/web/mysite.com/core/engine.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /home/admin/web/mysite.com/public_html/index.php on line 5

[Fri Sep 27 19:01:30.182883 2019] [:error] [pid 914] [client 157.245.138.57:46826] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/admin/web/mysite.com/public_html/../core/engine.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/admin/web/mysite.com/public_html/index.php on line 5
```

И сайт собственно выдает ошибку 500

Буду рад помощи, или совету

Answer (score 0):

Ну, навскидку -

```
[Fri Sep 27 19:01:30.182865 2019] [:error] [pid 914] [client 157.245.138.57:46826] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/admin/web/mysite.com/core/engine.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /home/admin/web/mysite.com/public_html/index.php on line 5

[Fri Sep 27 19:01:30.182883 2019] [:error] [pid 914] [client 157.245.138.57:46826] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/admin/web/mysite.com/public_html/../core/engine.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/admin/web/mysite.com/public_html/index.php on line 5
```

говорят о проблеме с правами на чтение соответствующих файлов. Проверьте, что эти каталоги есть и права на них как минимум есть на чтение для пользователя, под которым выполняеся php (или php_fpm, или apache, если php сконфигурирован как модуль апача)

А вот с

```
[Fri Sep 27 18:53:15.310579 2019] [:error] [pid 913] [client 157.245.138.57:46766] PHP Warning:  require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/home/admin/web/mysite.com/core/engine.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/admin/web/mysite.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp) in /home/admin/web/mysite.com/public_html/index.php on line 5
```

немного сложнее. [open_basedir](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) restriction in effect. Нужно лезть в php.ini.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я с вами согласен, но в том то и дело, что это идентичная копия прошлого сервера и его настроек. 
При проверке прав на каталоги и файлы все идентично, вот только в том сервере нет подобных ошибок в логах. Благодарю.

В php.ini 
Запись подобного рода
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/usr/share/php"
;

Answer (score 0):

ПРоблема решена, использую панель управления веб сервером vesta cp.
В конфиге по пути /home/admin/conf/web mysite.com.apache2.conf

в строке

```
php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/web/mysite.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp
```

Была приставка :/home/admin/tmp

Удалив ее, сайт успешно запустился

Правда появились проблемы, что теперь некоторые кнопки открывают старый сайт, но это уже наверное проблема с другой оперы, после переезда на новый домен.

Спасибо всем за помощь